# python multiprocesses better way of splitting an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

currently I am doing multiprocessing counting, I am trying to count the hashtags in a large amount of tweets which come in via an iterator I do know how many values are in these iterators (the counting itself is done in the `worker` method). Currently I am looping over the iterator and storing its values in a list once we have hit a block of data I start a worker thread which will call the `worker` method and I clear the list. I keep doing this until we run out of data in the iterator.

```
def __init__(self, poolSize, spaceTimeTweetCollection=None):
    sizeOfDataset = spaceTimeTweetCollection.count
    section = math.ceil(sizeOfDataset / poolSize)

    dataset = []
    counter = 0;

    for tweet in spaceTimeTweetCollection:
        counter += 1
        dataset.append(tweet)

        if sizeOfDataset % counter == 0 and counter >= section or counter >= sizeOfDataset:
            self.start_worker(dataset)
            dataset = []

def start_worker(self, dataset):
    p = Process(target=self.worker, args=((dataset),))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

is there a better way of doing this? my problem with this method is I need to convert the iterator into smaller lists which may not fit in memory!

Comment: Are you sure your CPU speed is what is deciding how long it takes for your program to run? The limiting factor is most likely to be your data supply or saving afterwards, which are unlikely to be affected by storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specifically want each worker to process a sequential interval of tweets, you may consider another approach:

Create a Queue. Start all worker threads simultaneously. Make the master thread read from spaceTimeTweetConnection and write them to the Queue. Let the worker threads read from the Queue.

Queue is thread-safe, so it will internally manage simultaneous reads.